# Normalizing a nonlinear plant in system identification in control

Tags: control, control-system, non-linear

I have calculated the "active power" and the "the reactive" power of a system in dq axis in nonlinear form and I am doing system identification on this "nonlinear" plant as a MIMO system.

The problem I have is that the system identification works with "normalized models" and this causes that either there is a steady state error or no correct model is identified.

Is there any way to normalize a nonlinear plant (input/output) other than using the per unit parameters?

Answer (score 0):

For best results, I suggest you need;

- to convert to linear control e.g. 1/x, log x or at least piecewise linear control, then
- have  tuning weights for MIMO signals all of order unity and not higher order terms.  e.g. position feedback for position control, current or acceleration feedback for likewise control.
- use per unit variables for grid control